# Breakpoint that breaks when data changes in a managed language

Tags: c#, debugging, breakpoints

I have a class with a list property that seems to lose an element under certain circumstances. I cannot find out when this happens.

So what I'd like to do is set up a Visual Studio breakpoint that will pause the program the moment this value changes. A conditional breakpoint would not work in this scenario, since I have no idea what is removing this breakpoint.

To put it another way, I want my program to stop the moment `myList.Count` evaluates to a new number.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is not possible in C# or any of the other .NET languages due to CLR limitations. The Visual Studio native code debugger supports data breakpoints ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/350dyxd0.aspx)) for C++ code which do exactly this but this is not supported for managed code. You could try to break on or intercept `Add` and `Remove` method calls on the collection as suggested in the other answer to this question.

Comment: Managed code ~= CLR/Microsoft Intermediate Language

Comment: Thanks. What do you mean by "~="? Is its right hand side an accurate definition of its left hand side? If not, can you give an accurate definition?

Comment: "~=" means "approximately equal to" in this context.

Comment: Thanks. What is its definition in general and not in this context?

Comment: It's now possible in VS2019 but only for .Net Core 3.0 and higher. See the other answer re VS2019.

Answer (score 9):

What about swapping out `List<T>` for `ObservableCollection<T>` and listen for the `CollectionChanged` event? It implements the `IList<T>` interface so there should be enough overlap in available methods to result in syntax and semantic compatibility.

Comment: This is a great idea!  I can't believe I didn't think of using an ObservableCollection earlier.  When CollectionChange is invoked, is there a way to trace the stack back to the line of code that made the change?

Comment: @Jason: Yeah, I think so. Since the events are raised synchronously the code that initiated the change should appear on the call stack somewhere right?

Comment: Makes sense to me.  I'll try this out next time I run into a similar situation.  Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

This is now possible in Visual Studio 2019.
See release notes here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes

This article goes into some detail using Preview 2.
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/break-when-value-changes-data-breakpoints-for-net-core-in-visual-studio-2019/

Note that this is for .NET Core only and not the soon-to-be-legacy full fledged Windows only .NET framework.

Comment: Interesting, but that feature seems to be for .NET Core only.

Comment: This Microsoft blog indicates that data breakpoints feature is only available for managed code in .Net Core 3.0 and higher: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/break-when-value-changes-data-breakpoints-for-net-core-in-visual-studio-2019/

Answer (score 2):

Subclass List<t> with your own class, then override Count (or Add/Remove) and add a breakpoint in the method you create.

EDIT: As mentioned in comments, this would require a great deal of effort since the Add and Remove methods aren't virtual; a complete rewrite of the methods would be needed.

Also, subclassing Collection<t> would apparently be a better solution (though I can't discern a reason why since Add/Remove aren't virtual members for Collection<t> either; comments?).

Comment: You can't override Add/Remove methods because they are not virtual. You can hide this methods and provide new versions, but in this case you should change all usage from List<MyType> to MyList<MyType>

Comment: This would be much more doable if you replace `List<T>` with `Collection<T>`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming Visual Studio is IDE.

Set a breakpoint, right click it, select condition, type myList.Count, and choose Has Changed.

Comment: "A conditional breakpoint would not work in this scenario, since I have no idea what is removing this breakpoint."

Comment: But that would stop execution and you can inspect the call stack for the offender. :)

Comment: It would, however; I would have to know where to set the breakpoint in this scenario.  I think conditional breakpoints are great and use them all the time, but in this scenario at the time I wrote this question, I had no idea what line of code was causing the issue.  I appreciate your thoughts on this question however.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can set data breakpoints in visual studio but this is going to be difficult to do for managed code, as the garbage collector may move the object around. That said, you may still be able to pull it off. You will have to enable native debugging for your process. Load SOS in the immediate window and use !DumpObject to find the address of the backing store for the `Count` property. Using this address, create a new data breakpoint with this address and then continue and trigger the issue.

Comment: I have never tried this as it relates to debugging, but could you not pin the object to prevent the GC from moving it around?

Answer (score 1):

Find all usages for this particular property and add breakpoint to all lines that removes elements from this list.

Or you may create your own IList implementation and set breakpoint to Remove method (you can't subclass List without changing all you clients, because List::Remove isn't virtual).

Comment: I went with the "Find all usages" suggestion.  I was hoping for an easier solution, but I understand why it's not possible in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

This is maybe more of a question than an answer, but you can step into Framework code when debugging, provided you set up your Visual studio that way. It could be that you can then put the breakpoint into the actual List implementation.

Answer (score 0):

this may sound too out of the way or complex but can you use timer/background thread to keep testing the count value and do a `Debugger.Break()` whenever it finds the value different from its previous instance.

Comment: An interesting idea, however; it would not give me the results I'm looking for.  I want to know the exact line that caused the change.