# Set breakpoint in Visual Studio when a member variable is accessed C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, breakpoints

Is there a way to set a breakpoint when the member variable data is accessed in Visual studio for C# code?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to set a dynamic breakpoint in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3815202/is-there-a-way-to-set-a-dynamic-breakpoint-in-c)

Comment: It would possibly be much easier if you changed the member variable to a property and then set the break point on the get accessor

Answer (score 2):

You can't achieve this for a regular field, because the debugger can not break on a simple memory copy operation. However, let's say we have a field called `UncleName`, like so:

```
    public static string UnclesName = "Bob";
```

You could turn it into a property:

```
    public static string _unclesName = "Bob";
    public static string UnclesName { get { return _unclesName; } set { _unclesName = value; } }
```

What really happens, is the compiler generates two methods for you under the hood, one to *get* the data from the field, and one to *set* it.

The debugger *can* can break on methods, and since we have now changed our data to be accessed through a method, namely the `UnclesName.get()` method, we can insert a breakpoint on the `get` keyword of our property, and have the debugger break every time the data is accessed.

Comment: It would be nice if Visual Studio could also set a breakpoint on a single accessor of a so-called auto-property, for example `public static string UnclesName { get; set; }`, but it does not appear to work as of the current version of Visual Studio (VS2013).

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Microsoft responded to a feature request for it: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/408762/unable-to-set-breakpoint-to-c-automatic-property - Marked it as won't fix sadly.